# Automatically convert from latlon to planar

Tags: r, sp

I work with library(sp) and points in latitude longitude, with this projection:

```
proj4string(pts) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
```

But some functions (such as sp::spample) require planar coordinates (for good reasons).

Sometimes I work with points in Europe, sometimes in Asia, etc.

Is there a best practice to project to planar coordinates without having to manually specify in which epsg-zone the coordinates are?

This will do it (but knowledge that points are in Finland must decide "2393").

```
pts.transfor <- spTransform(pts, CRS("+init=epsg:2393"))
```

How can "2393" be found automatically in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about "best" practice but a couple of options spring to mind:

1. Use the longitudes in the data to work out which UTM zone the points mostly lie. UTM zones are simple divisions of the globe by longitude bands. Then work out the EPSG code for that UTM zone. They are consecutive numbers, so fairly easy to compute from a given latitude. Don't worry too much if your points cover two or three zones, just pick the "middlest".
2. Create a custom proj4 string for a projection centred at the centroid of your data. An azimuthal equidistant projection, for example, can be centred anywhere on the planet, and for small enough regions there shouldn't be any problem with distortion. The resulting string will look something like `"+proj=aeqd +lon_0=23.4 +lat_0=1-0.23"` (but check with proj4 documentation, you may have to specify some other parameters). Project your lat-long to that and you'll have a pretty good planar projection for anywhere on the planet (for data not over a huge area).

Comment: Nice suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

EPSG is a **key** (not a **zone** number like in UTM) for a specific set of projection parameters and the command:

```
$ grep -B 1 '<2393>' /usr/share/proj/epsg 
# KKJ / Finland Uniform Coordinate System
<2393> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=1 \
       +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl \
       +towgs84=-96.062,-82.428,-121.753,4.801,0.345,-1.376,1.496\
       +units=m +no_defs  <>
```

will give you a glimpse behind the scenes of the proj.4 "landscape". The not easy to read text gives you the info that:

- `+proj=tmerc` is a transverse mercator projection
- `+lat_0=0` the center parallel is at the equator
- `+lon_0=27` the central meriadian at 27 degrees east
- `+k=1` a scaling factor is not applied
- `+x_0=3500000` the false easting parameter an offest to prevent the usage of negative number in your coordinate system
- `+y_0=0` the false northing .dito but zero
- `+ellps=intl` the International 1909 (Hayford) Ellipsoid
- `+units=m` the coordinate unit is metre
- `towgs84=...` indicates that the coordinate system is shifted

You could use the web page [http://spatialreference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/kkj-finland-uniform-coordinate-system/) to be sure which EPSG is the right one and in which area the projection is valid and read the detailed [documentation](ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/proj/OF90-284.pdf) of proj.4, to understand the different projection types and their parameters.

I assume that [`CRS` class](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/CRS) insde the package `sp` is built against the [proj.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PROJ.4) tool und uses the same  initialization "rituals" to grab the right coordinate system parameters.

Comment: +1 for a nice explanation of the proj.4 projection format.

Comment: Thanks, this made me take a large step in understanding. Thanks.